# Can't fit buttons in code

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to make working button and fit it in this code i have below. My problem is that anywhere i put actionlisteners or other stuff it always gives me weird errors. I want to make my button b1 to print text when i press it. I would really appreciate help. Im just beginner.

```
public class Simulator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean suc1,suc2,suc3,suc4,suc5,suc6,suc7;

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simulator");
        f.setSize(500, 400);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Find");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("Stop");
        b1.setBounds(20,335,80,25);
        b2.setBounds(110,335,80,25);
        b3.setBounds(200,335,80,25);
        b4.setBounds(395,335,80,25);
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(b4);

}
}
```

Comment: Although looks like Java, you should tag the question to clarify what platform you are using

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) (& that would include imports).  For the sake of your future sanity, avoid `null` layouts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button b1 was pressed");

        }
    });
```

EDIT:

Seems to work fine for me. Here's the full main() method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean suc1,suc2,suc3,suc4,suc5,suc6,suc7;

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simulator");
        f.setSize(500, 400);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Button b1 was pressed");

            }
        });
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Find");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("Stop");
        b1.setBounds(20,335,80,25);
        b2.setBounds(110,335,80,25);
        b3.setBounds(200,335,80,25);
        b4.setBounds(395,335,80,25);
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(b4);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: When i use your method it doesnt allow me to put that button in my frame

Comment: I got it not to give me error but then my button doesn't show in frame, it just disappears. i cant use setBounds to that button nor add it to frame with f1.add(b1);

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what i looked for. Everything works now. Thanks

Comment: Have to down vote any code that uses `f.setLayout(null);` without very, *very* good reasons to do so.  I've added an example that uses layouts & borders.  It should adapt gracefully if Oracle decides to double the size of the font used for buttons (and a load of other possibilities).

Comment: @Andrew it wasn't my idea/decision and that wasn't part of the question. I was just trying to help the OP with ActionListener and talking about layout is out of scope and it's unfair to impose a downvote for that reason but thanks for providing a reason at least.

Comment: @Bala Yes, I just noticed that and tried to reverse my vote, but it was 'too late unless edited'.  My bad.  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Simulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Simulator");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // Unnecessary, just set the preferred size of the
                // custom(?) component that renders the simulation,
                // use layouts, & pack() the frame when done.
                //f.setSize(500, 400);

                f.setResizable(false);

                // Bad idea.  Will cause trouble until fixed.
                //f.setLayout(null);

                // Play with the numbers for different effects.
                // If the edge of the buttons is not supposed to align
                // with the 'simulation' panel, borders can be added to
                // the elements to create that effect.

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                gui.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(10,30,10,30) );

                JPanel simulation = new JPanel();
                simulation.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,300));
                simulation.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                gui.add(simulation, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(50,5) );
                gui.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JPanel westButtons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,10,10));

                JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
                JButton b2 = new JButton("Clear");
                JButton b3 = new JButton("Find");
                JButton b4 = new JButton("Stop");

                westButtons.add(b1);
                westButtons.add(b2);
                westButtons.add(b3);

                buttonPanel.add(westButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);

                buttonPanel.add(b4, BorderLayout.EAST);

                f.setContentPane(gui);

                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // ensure the UI is built on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

[image: Sceenshot of GUI]

Comment: And you don't seem to address the OP's question about using `ActionListener` for `b1` .

Comment: @Bala R  Yeah.. I completely **missed** the bit about the `ActionListener` - which is kind of ironic, given that was the crux of the question!  I figure there is not much point adding it now, since your code covers the AL.  I'll leave my code, simply because it might demonstrate to the OP how the layout might be achieved.